# Login With Facebook Doesn't Respond On iOS 11 After Upgrading SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.x

I have application on production with Facebook SDK version 4.24.0. Everything works fine with login with facebook in production application.

I have updated Facebook SDK version to 4.35.0. This version works fine in iOS 9 and 10. But in iOS 11 asks for permission like {AppName} wants to use "facebook.com" To Sign In. After I clicked on continue, nothing appears. No WebView no appswitching.

This is how I handle login :

```
 FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[login logInWithReadPermissions:PERMISSIONS fromViewController:self.fromViewController handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {

    if (error) {
        // Process error
        //   [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
        [self handleFacebookError:error andResult:result];



    } else if (result.isCancelled) {
        // Handle cancellations

        [self handleFacebookSessionClosed];

        /**
         Letting the delegates know that the session was closed.
         */
        [self informDelegateWithLoginStatus:TRUAuthenticationStatus_Error
                                    message:nil];
        [self informDelegateWithAccountMergeStatus:TRUAuthenticationStatus_Error
                                           message:nil];

    } else {
        // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
        // should check if specific permissions missing
        [self handleFacebookSessionOpen];


    }

}];
```

And if I set login behavior to FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb, It shows a pop up which like shown in below I don't want.
[image: Login With Facebook]

I have this properties in info.plist file:

```
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fbapiXXX</string>
    <string>fbauth</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-apiXXX</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fb</string>
</array>
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>facebook.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>fbcdn.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>akamaihd.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

And I handle openURL in application delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:annotation
            ];}
```

When I downgrade to Facebook SDK 4.24.0 It works fine. What I've tried so far;

I have tried making FBSDKLoginManager *login variable global. It didn't worked. 
I have tried activating KeyChain. It didn't work.